# How to keep Node uv_run from exiting when hosting own thread in an add on?

Tags: node.js

I have a custom server that runs in its own posix thread in a native Node Add On.

What is the proper way to keep the node process running the uv_run event loop?  In other words, if I start the server in my Add On via a script, my process will exit at the end of the script instead of keeping the event loop running.

I've tried adding a SignalWatcher via process.on and that still exits.  I didn't see anything else in the process object for doing this from script.

In node.cc, there is this comment:

```
  // Create all the objects, load modules, do everything.
  // so your next reading stop should be node::Load()!
  Load(process_l);

  // All our arguments are loaded. We've evaluated all of the scripts. We
  // might even have created TCP servers. Now we enter the main eventloop. If
  // there are no watchers on the loop (except for the ones that were
  // uv_unref'd) then this function exits. As long as there are active
  // watchers, it blocks.
  uv_run(uv_default_loop());

  EmitExit(process_l);
```

What does the Add On have to do?

I've tried calling uv_ref(uv_default_loop()) in the main thread in my Add On when starting the server/pthread but the process still exits.

Note: I *can* bind to a TCP/UDP port or set a timer and that will keep uv_run from exiting, but I would like to do this the "correct" way.

Comment: Additional information: calling uv_ref(uv_default_loop()) does seem to hold the event loop, but then my server object gets released after 10 seconds or so.

Comment: I think the fix is to hold the server object by deriving it from ObjectWrap and calling Ref() and Unref() when the script calls start() and stop() on my server, respectively.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question (I'm guessing! Did it work?)

Comment: [I would have updated my original post but I had to wait a period before I could update it]
I found that I had to do both (calling uv_ref and Ref).